Linux kernel printk disassemble
This is in continuation of an existing SO post here.
I have the following function in a dummy kernel module for x86_64 platform.
static void dummy_function_1(int arg1, char arg2) {
    printk(KERN_INFO "dummy_function_1: arg1=%d, arg2=%c\n", arg1, arg2);
    dummy_function_2("Hello", (struct dummy_struct){.a = arg1, .b = arg2});
}

I did disassembly of this to show relocations using -r :
0000000000000120 <dummy_function_1>:
 120:   55                      push   %rbp
 121:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
 124:   41 54                   push   %r12
 126:   53                      push   %rbx
 127:   89 fb                   mov    %edi,%ebx
 129:   41 89 f4                mov    %esi,%r12d
 12c:   40 0f b6 d6             movzbl %sil,%edx
 130:   89 fe                   mov    %edi,%esi
 132:   48 c7 c7 00 00 00 00    mov    $0x0,%rdi
            135: R_X86_64_32S   .rodata.str1.8+0x118
 139:   e8 00 00 00 00          call   13e <dummy_function_1+0x1e>
            13a: R_X86_64_PLT32 _printk-0x4
 13e:   45 0f b6 e4             movzbl %r12b,%r12d
 142:   49 c1 e4 20             shl    $0x20,%r12
 146:   89 de                   mov    %ebx,%esi
 148:   4c 09 e6                or     %r12,%rsi
 14b:   48 c7 c7 00 00 00 00    mov    $0x0,%rdi
            14e: R_X86_64_32S   .rodata.str1.1+0x24
 152:   e8 79 ff ff ff          call   d0 <dummy_function_2>


We can clearly see 4 bytes of zeroes at addresses 0x135 and 0x13a. I did memory dump of this function on a running system and I can see that these 4 zero-bytes were replaced by dynamic linker :
crash> rd ffffffffc0000110 16
ffffffffc0000110:  9090909090909090 9090909090909090   ................
ffffffffc0000120:  89535441e5894855 d6b60f40f48941fb   UH..ATS..A..@...
ffffffffc0000130:  004148c7c748fe89 0f45c1100e72e8c0   ..H..HA...r...E.
ffffffffc0000140:  de8920e4c149e4b6 4024c7c748e6094c   ..I.. ..L..H..$@
ffffffffc0000150:  00ffffff79e8c000 0000000000000000   ...y............
ffffffffc0000160:  9090909090909090 9090909090909090   ................
ffffffffc0000170:  e5894855fa1e0ff3 e8c0004000c7c748   ....UH..H...@...
ffffffffc0000180:  ccccc35dc1100e2c 000000000000cccc   ,...]...........

So, we can conclude that 0x135 is replaced with 0x484100c0 and 0x13a is replaced with 0x720e10c1. And that is all I could conclude. I want to know further what these newer bytes mean? And is it really possible to determine the virtual address where this string was stored, that I can memory dump and confirm?
EDIT
I got a random idea to use an online tool to convert the bytes from the memory dump back to assembly :
48 c7 c7 48 41 00 c0 e8 72 0e 10 c1
and I got :
0:  48 c7 c7 48 41 00 c0    mov    rdi,0xffffffffc0004148
7:  e8 72 0e 10 c1          call   0xffffffffc1100e7e 

Now if I take dump of location 0xffffffffc0004148 :
crash> rd 0xffffffffc0004148 10
ffffffffc0004148:  5f796d6d75643601 6e6f6974636e7566   .6dummy_function
ffffffffc0004158:  31677261203a315f 677261202c64253d   _1: arg1=%d, arg
ffffffffc0004168:  0000000a63253d32 75646f4d794d3601   2=%c.....6MyModu
ffffffffc0004178:  74696e49203a656c 676e697a696c6169   le: Initializing
ffffffffc0004188:  4d794d2065687420 ee000a656c75646f    the MyModule...
crash>

Perfect, some familiar string. But I am still not sure what those first two bytes 0x0136 at 0xffffffffc0004148 do before the actual string start?

Does this answer your question? What do R_X86_64_32S and R_X86_64_64 relocation mean?

0x0136 is printk() prefix for log level. Read about that. https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/include/linux/kern_levels.h#L14 So it's KERN_SOH followed by KERN_INFO followed by the message.

So, you've got several questions here mashed together.

I want to know further what these newer bytes mean?

These are addresses relocated to their proper location as requested by the relocation records.
E.g.
135: R_X86_64_32S   .rodata.str1.8+0x118

means the loader must replace this record with an absolute load-time address of .rodata.str1.8+0x118, but it needs to truncate it to 32 bit, and it has to be sign-extendable to its proper 64 bit value (because the mov imm32, %rdi command needs it that way). In your case, that address is 0xffffffffc0004148, and its truncated 32 bit value is 0xc0004148.
R_X86_64_PLT32 relocation works similarly but it is PC-relative because call instruction needs it that way; so the exact value depends not only on _printk load-time location in the kernel, but also on the location of relocation point itself.
You can google them to get better understanding on how they work (in fact, there are plenty of SO questions on the relocations with great answers).

And is it really possible to determine the virtual address where this string was stored, that I can memory dump and confirm?

Well, yes. As you figured out yourself, R_X86_64_32S type of relocation, when relocated, contains the final address. One could also figure out any and all symbols in the kernel module knowing offsets of the symbols in the module and its load location. /sys/modules/<module>/sections files show where each module section gets loaded at.

But I am still not sure what those first two bytes 0x0136 at 0xffffffffc0004148 do before the actual string start?

That would be KERN_INFO. It is not a parameter for _printk as some might think. See What exactly expands the KERN_INFO, and where it is implemented? for more information

From System.map file I can see ffffffff81100fb0 T _printk, so why it was a candidate for relocation? The entry 13a: R_X86_64_PLT32 _printk-0x4 did not make sense to me as it could have been based on the value in System.map right?

Is it because ffffffff81100fb0 T _printk from System.map is just an offset value and what we need is the final address. Since kernel can be loaded anywhere, we make it a candidate for relocation so that those 4 bytes can be overwritten with real address of _printk during dynamic (runtime) linking ?

No, ffffffff81100fb0 is the actual "final" address of _printk. System.map stores addresses, not offsets. What you see in your disassembly is wrong because, like I said earlier, call has a PC-relative argument (THAT is offset). As such, the actual call target depends not only on the argument value but also on the instruction location. In order to correctly disassemble call, you need to correctly specify its IP (and your online disassembler assumed it is 7 which is wrong). Honestly, if you are meddling with assembly and relocations, do read up on assembly and relocations!

As for we make it a candidate for relocation part - not exactly because of that. We make it a candidate for relocation because we make no assumptions on external symbols location (ASLR is a thing but not just because of it). When we build a kernel module, we know which symbols are there but we don't know where they are. The kernel is intentionally a black box; kernel module build process don't look at the kernel image. You can rebuild a kernel with other parameters, so all the symbols would move to new locations, and your kernel module would still load and work without rebuilding.

would be KERN_INFO --> is KERN_INFO and use links to Elixir, they are better since one may browse the code.
